# Match whole string with spaces if it contains at least a letter

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I need a RegEx that matches a string which contains letter, digits, some special chars and spaces. However, the RegEx has to reject a string which is composed only by spaces.
I've created a pattern, but it does not work.

```
import re

pattern = r"^[/<>'\.\,\-\?\[\] \w\d]+$"

print bool(re.match(pattern, "Hi, how are you?"))
print bool(re.match(pattern, "Hi, how are you? &*() "))
print bool(re.match(pattern, " "))
```

this is the output of the previous snippet:

```
True
False
True
```

I need the third test to fail as the second does.
I know I could do it using more than just e regex, but I would like to know if it is possible only using regex.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead in your regex:

```
patter = r"^(?!\s*$)[<>'.,?\[\] \w\d-]+$"
```

`(?!\s*$)` is the negative lookahead to fail the match if input has just 0 or more spaces.

**Test:**

```
>>> print bool(re.match(patter, " "))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a positive lookahead

```
^(?=.*\S)[<>'.,?\[\] \w\d-]+$
```

which makes it mandatory to have a `\S` or non space character in the string.